# How can I retrieve specific object in a nested structure in mongodb?

Tags: mongoose, mongodb-query

Given the following structure below, I want to retrieve the 2nd product object given this shopName. I can only think of getting all the product objects with this query: `Shop.find({ shopName: shopName}).select('products')`. How can I modify it to achieve what I want, appreciate it!

```
"shopName": "jmart",
"products": [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Clean and Clear Deep Clean Cleanser 100g",
        "slug": "8d1c895c-6911-4fc8-a34c-89c6948233d7",
        "price": 4.5,
        "discount_price": 0,
        "category": "Health and Beauty",
        "sale": false,
        "subcategory": "personal care",
        "color": "black",
        "article": "Clean and Clear",
        "quantity": 9,
        "img": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/swifty-products.appspot.com/o/Jmart%2FBeauty%2FClean%20and%20Clear%20Deep%20Clean%20Cleanser%20100g.jpg?alt=media",
        "vendor": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Clean and Clear"
        },
        "ratings": {
            "star_ratings": 0,
            "votes": 0
        },
        "isAvailable": true
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Colgate Total Pro Breath Health",
        "slug": "67626dae-1537-40d8-837d-483e5759ada0",
        "price": 4.5,
        "discount_price": 0,
        "category": "Health and Beauty",
        "sale": false,
        "subcategory": "personal care",
        "color": "black",
        "article": "Colgate",
        "quantity": 9,
        "img": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/swifty-products.appspot.com/o/Jmart%2FBeauty%2FColgate%20Total%20Pro%20Breath%20Health.jpg?alt=media",
        "vendor": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Colgate"
        },
        "ratings": {
            "star_ratings": 0,
            "votes": 0
        },
        "isAvailable": true
    },
  ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can use the [$slice](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/#mongodb-projection-proj.-slice) operator to return the nth array element.

`{ $slice: [ <number to skip>, <number to return> ] }`

```js
const products = await Shop.find(
  { shopName: shopName },
  { products: { $slice: [1, 1] } } // Skip the first element of array and return the next 1 element
).select("products");
```

Comment: hi @Vishnu, how do you suppose I update a specific field in the second element based on the slug?  The following does not work  ```Shop.find({ shopName: shopName}).update({products: {$elemMatch: {slug: slug}}}, { $set: { price: req.body.price } }```